# How can I erase other versions of Ubuntu (backtrack, studio 10.04) from my computer's HD and boot selection.

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I have 4 choices for OS's, 3 on first boot screen (Winows 7, Backtrack 5, and Ubuntu Studio 10.04). Backtrack and Studio are problematic and I wish to erase all traces of them but leave my Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.xx wubi intact. What is the best way to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you have all this on one partition?

Comment: Yes, all on one 2 TB HDD.

Comment: In the future please give every OS his own partition. When I set up Ubuntu I take one partition for the system (let's say 40GB), one for home(the largest slice for all my stuff), and a swap partition that only needs 4GB (depends on your RAM). You have 2TB of space... that's a lot. You should play by the term: Devide et impera ... you probably know what it means. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little awkward. One way could be to erase all files that belong to Backtrack and Studio...and than also modify grub to delete that two options.

Probably better way would be to try out that OS Uninstaller software.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller

Be careful from where you run it. I recommend you to use live system for that.